# Does the verb “trounce” have dual meanings of active and passive voice in its gerund form,”trouncing”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

There was the following sentence in Time magazine (June 28) article titled, “Reform in Japan – The third arrow” analyzing Japan’s Prime Minister, Shinzo Abe’s so called, Abenomix policies to revitalize Japanese economy.

> Nowadays, Mr. Abe faces little serious opposition outside the LDP: the
>   opposition Democratic Party of Japan is nowhere near reviving itself
>   after its **trouncing** at the polls in December 2010.

I was under impression that the verb “trounce” is a transitive verb, therefore “trouncing” means “beating sb,” e.g. rival or enemy.

CED defines “trounce” as transitive verb: to defeat a competitor by a large amount.

OED defines “trounce” as transitive verb: (accompanied with object)

1. Defeat heavily in a contest.
2. Rebuke or punish severely.

OALED defines "trounce" as verb: to defeat sb completely.

Merriam- Webster defines “trounce” as transitive verb: to defeat (someone or something) easily and thoroughly

In the above quote, “its trouncing” appears to refer to DPJ’s crushing defeat in December 2010 Upper House election.

Can trounce which all dictionaries at hand define as a transitive verb be used in the passive sense of “being completely defeated,” or an intransitive verb like 'lose' in a noun or gerund form?

Comment: it's just a noun, as you see it there. no big deal.

Comment: Just FYI, you mention "crashing defeat". The common phrase is "crushing defeat".

Comment: "after its trouncing" = after it **received** a trouncing. *cf.* "After the **admonishing,** he changed his ways."

Comment: @JoeBlow You're right.

Comment: @Joe Blow. Thanks for your pointing out my misspelling. I corrected it.

Comment: @Kris. I have no problem if it were 'after it received a trouncing. It's clear. Whilst "after its trouncing" on its alone can be taken in both ways of "after LDP's trouncing DPJ" and "after DPJ's trouncing LDP" if the reader is not familiar with the background.

Comment: Yes, it *can* be read as a verb, *if* there's a *who:* "after its trouncing **the opponent** at the polls".

Comment: **Most gerunds** of transitive verbs have the potential for dual meanings as a noun.

Comment: @Peter Shor. That's a new learning for me. I was under impression that the verb defined as only transitive verb (as trounce) retains the 'active' meaning all through as against passive meaning (be trounced) when transfered into noun and gerund.

Comment: If you're saying "trouncing" could be interpreted **both ways** - then yes, trouncing is a **100.00% ambiguous word**. It can mean either direction.  But so what?  25% of English is incredibly ambiguous.  If I say "Regarding the defeat, Brasil said ..." --- that sentence is 1000% ambiguous.  It could mean "the defeat they handed out" or "the defeat they were handed". This is totally unsurprising to an English speaker.  I mean we don't even have a way to say hello when it's after 5pm.

Comment: @Peter Shor. I doubt it. At the top of mind, losing (lose＋ing)doesn't have the meaning of winning （win＋ing）as well as winning doesn't have the meaning of losing. Saving (save＋ing)doesn't have the meaning of wasting (waste＋ing), and vice versa.

Comment: @Yoichi: for *winning*, it can refer to either the act of *winning* or the direct object (what is won). *"My winning was a complete fluke"* or *"my winnings weren't very large"*. In this case, the different meanings are distinguished by singular and plural, but it nevertheless has two meanings.

Comment: *Trouncing of* means "victory over" while *trouncing by* means "defeat at the hands of".  Actually, it has nothing to do with that noun's status as a gerund: the word *defeat* can be used the same way.  "Augustus' defeat of Pompey" *vs* "Pompey's defeat by Augustus".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me *trounce* can be either transitive or intransitive.

'Liverpool trounced United in the FA Cup', is transitive.

'United were trounced in the FA Cup' is both intransitive and passive.

'Trouncing' is a gerund noun, and issues of active/passive, transitive/intransitive do not apply.

Comment: Right, it couldn't be more straightforward.

Comment: Hi @WS2, can you address the issue **"Why do dictionaries define “trounce” solely as a transitive verb"** ...?  For me the answer is "dictionaries are risible, ignore them" but I can see Yoichi's point.  Do you have any thought on this?  Cheers!

Comment: @JoeBlow Is it not the case that most transitive verbs can also appear intransitive if used passively? E.g. in 'he hit the ball', 'hit' is transitive. 'He was hit by the ball'is also transitive. But 'he was hit', is intransitive. To be honest I am not enough of a grammarian to understand all the implications of transitive/intransitive. People like John Lawler talk about 'ditransitive' verbs. I have never studied grammar beyond an elementary level. You need someone like JL or Edwin Ashworth to take this up.

Comment: @WS2.I found an exact example of  your theory - distinction of tv and iv doesn't apply to gerund noun today in the sentence in an article of The New Yorker (Aug.1. 2014), that reads "Prior to Buswell’s hiring by the Hall, in 1983, the busts were molded by his predecessor, Jack Worthington, using photos and the player’s hat size."

Comment: @YoichiOishi I think the point is that a gerund is a noun. And transitive/ intransitive is a way of understanding verbs. So it is irrelevant to gerunds. I do find it quite difficult to understand what is troubling you about this.

Comment: @WS2. I know gerund is noun. We call gerund 動名詞- transferred noun (from verb) in Japanese. We learn it in middle school at 13 years old. It may have been my prejudice. But I was under the vague impression up until yesterday that the original nature of verb (as transitive and intransitive) is inherited straight even when being transferred into gerund (though I knew ‘defeat’ can be used both ways of winning and losing). And again, four major English dictionaries define ‘trounce” SOLELY as a transitive verb in accord.

Comment: Cont.And I can’t be so bold to say as a non-native speaker that editors of all these dictionaries are dumb and illiterate to forget to include ‘trounce’ as an intransitive verb.

Comment: @YoichiOishi And is this the only transitive verb you have ever encountered which can be made to perform intransitively?

Comment: I don't want to discuss and repeat the same argument endlessly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16157/discussion-between-yoichi-oishi-and-ws2).

Answer (score 1):

[Trouncing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trouncing) in the sentence is  a noun.

> - (Noun) - sound defeat

Actually I found one dictionary that suggests that 'to trounce' can be intransitive,
but has no relation to the meaning in your sentence.

[To trounce](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trounce):

> v.intr.
>
> - To censure something or someone forcefully: "I was out to trounce on every digression and indiscretion conducted (or should I say semiconducted) in this performance" (Robert Maxwell Stern).

Source: The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language.

Comment: As far as I checked, none of dictionaries I listed above doesn't carry heading or definitions of 'trouncing' as a noun.

Comment: It's completely commonplace in English that you can transition - anything - as a noun. You can use an adjective like "fast" as a noun.  (I don't know the etiquette for dictionaries to report on this.)

Comment: @Joe Blow. Everybody knows that we can transform verb into noun or gerund by fixing 'ing.'  It's not my concern at all. My interest is that "trounce" which is essentialily active voice in verb form is transformed into passive form - being trounced / beaten (by the opposition), and gets dual meanings of active (trounce) and passive (be trounced).

Comment: Hmm, sorry for the misunderstanding.  (1) "trouncing" is a noun.  (2) regarding "Why 'trouncing' is not in dictionaries?" (you mention that just above): I have no idea.  (3) Are you asking if you can use "TROUNCE" as a noun? (Answer, yes, as with basically any word in English you can "whackily" but clearly use it as a noun ... "nice trounce, dude."). If you are asking (4) **"Can trounce be used as a transitive verb?"** could you give an example?  (I think the answer is "obviously, sure" but I may be unclear.)

Comment: @JoeBlow. I never asked you your (3) and (4) questions. 'Trounce' is a transitive verb all the way and out and out as I quoted the definitions of CED, OED, OALED, and Merriam-Webster in my question. No dictionary shows 'trounce" as an intransitive verb. There's no room for misunderstanding.

Comment: OK, sorry for the time waste.  I seem to completely misunderstand what you are asking. (Just FTR I still do not know what you are asking - heh!!)  **Trounce is both transitive or intransitive -- see WS2's answer.** That's settled.  If the question is "why is trounce shown only as transitive in dictionaries" - I have no answer.  My guess is "English dictionaries are pretty much hopeless."  if you "don't believe" that trounce is both transitive or intransitive (and fair enough), the proof is just to use it in sentences - all of which WS2 has done.

Comment: @Joe Blow. I don’t mean to be offensive to you at all. But all four major English dictionaries define “trounce” solely as a transitive verb, and some EL&U users say it’s both tv and iv. Then the issue becomes whose opinion I should follow - dictionaries or individual's? It’s a dilemma for a non-native English learner like me to whom dictionaries are only reliable sources to consult when checking the meaning of words and phrases. I cannot throw away CED, OED, OALED, and Merriam-Webster by swearing they are all “hopeless” and useless because they don’t indicate intransitive usage of ‘trounce.’

Comment: Cont. However, I think I got a telling clue to my question with WS2’s answer that suggests “in gerund noun form, issues of active/passive, transitive/intransitive do not apply,” like ice in solid form becomes shapeless when it turns into water, though no English dicionary has explained it.

Comment: Right, it goes without saying that “in gerund noun form, issues of active/passive, transitive/intransitive do not apply,”  BUT ADDITIONALLY, it's just the case that trounce can be either transitive or intransitive.  Regarding the important question: "Why are dictionaries useless?"  As I've said, I simply have absolutely no answer to that question. I've always just assumed dictionaries are completely useless. I have absolutely no further info or guess on that - sorry!!!

Answer (score 1):

When a verbs nouning is phrased in the possessive, it generally indicates passive voice.

> My trouncing at the event was quite thorough.

Refers to my to having been thoroughly trounced at the event. There is also "give sb. a verging", and "get a verbing (from)", most commonly with an aggressive verb, e.g. "give sb. a thrashing" or "give sb. a firm talking-to". The above quote could be rephrased, "I got a thorough trouncing at the event."

However, there are very similar looking usages which take the active voice.

> My speaking at the event was not an endorsement of all of the organizers' views

The "speaking" here is not something I got at the event, but something I did at the event.

Answer (score 0):

If your actual question is, "Can 'trouncing' be used in both active and passive voice?"

Then again the answer is "sure, absolutely, it's completely commonplace."

> You're trouncing the hell out of him.
>
> Historic trouncings, 101.
>
> I'm trouncing you dude.
>
> After a trouncing, heads tend to roll.
>
> Let us review the trouncing.
>
> After trouncing A, she went on to trouncing B.
>
> Watch the trouncing live tonight on NHK.
>
> I'm watching Germany trouncing Brasil right now.

No problem.

---

If your actual question is, can trounce be used like this:

> I trounced him!
>
> She sure trounced him.
>
> We trounced the hell out of the other team.
>
> Germany trounced Brasil who for some reason in the last ten years have become a country of
>   star-focussed assholes rather than a country of teamplay.
>
> I got trounced.
>
> You trounced me

Then the answer is "yeah, absolutely, it's 100% commonplace."

It's that simple:  "Yes".